# Why Android theme does not affect elements inside of fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme

I have an Activity that hosts `FrameLayout` and dynamically displays custom fragments.

My goal is to have in styles.xml defined button style that applies to all buttons inside all fragments.

This is my **styles.xml** file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/bt</item>
</style>

<style name="bt" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">#992323</item>
</style>
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.app.LoginActivity">


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally **fragment.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.app.LoginBackupKeyFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Got it!"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="BackupKeyGotItButtonClicked"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

But the style is not applied! Why?

**EDIT 15.11.2015**

After reading this question, I think I should mention that I use custom `onCreateView` function in my fragment and it looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AppThemeDark);

    // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

    View fragmentView = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_new, container, false);

    pass1 = (EditText)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.login_new_pass1);

    return fragmentView;
}
```

**EDIT 2 15.11.2015**
this is my **manifest XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application>

        <activity android:name=".StartUpActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeDark"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT 3 !!IMPORTANT!!**

I have noticed this has to be related with

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/bt</item>
```

as e.g. adding this

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#f00</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#0f0</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#00f</item>
```

into `AppThemeDark` style works and shows ok in fragment. just `android:buttonStyle` and simmilaruly e.g. `android.editTextStyle` does not work.

Comment: Please post your manifest.xml code

Comment: I have posted the manifest

Answer (score 0):

May be too late, but if I understand correctly you want to set different `colorControlNormal`, `colorControlActivated` and `colorControlHighlight` than specified globally in your theme and apply it just for a button. I had similar problem (I wanted white accent color for `EditText`) and I've resolved it like follows:

1. create style in `values/styles`:

   `<style name="ColorOverwrite" parent="AppTheme">
       <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white_54p</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
       <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white_54p</item>
       <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
   </style>`
2. add `app:theme="@style/ColorOverwrite"` (**UPDATE** `app:theme="..."` is now deprecated, we should use `android:theme=""`) for certain control (EditText in my case)

   `<EditText
       android:id="@+id/id"
       android:textColor="@color/colorBlueLight"
       android:inputType="text"
       app:theme="@style/ColorOverwrite"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`
3. make sure you **don't** set at the same time `style="@style/somestyle"` for that control or you'll get an error.

[Example image showing applied theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBohe.png) - `EditText` in red rectangle has my custom theme, `EditText` in yellow rectangle shows default color style from theme

Answer (score 0):

You can just override `onGetLayoutInflater` at your Fragment

```
    /*Set Light theme for the fragment;It overrides activity theme and set Light*/
    override fun onGetLayoutInflater(bundle: Bundle?): LayoutInflater {
        val contextThemeWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.AppTheme_Light)

        // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
        val inflater = super.onGetLayoutInflater(bundle)
        return inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper)
    }
```

And also if you want to get a color attr from the overried theme do this in fragment:

```
val colorInt = MaterialColors.getColor(getLayoutInflater().context, R.attr.colorAccent, Color.WHITE)
```